# set inital values for fuzzy logic controrller via simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, fuzzy-logic

I am using simulink to simulate my network. In my network, each element (Node) is represented as fuzzy inference system (FIS). Each FIS has a set of inputs and one output, the output from this FIS will be an input to another FIS to participate in calculation of the value to the other element.
each node is represented via FIS, and all the nodes(FIS’s)are connected with each other.

I connect them all in simulink and they work fine, but I need to set a specific initial value for each element to start the simulation.

However, i used the Model explore in Simulink – Model work space to set for each FIS the initial value but unfortunately now I have an error that related for each FIS in my model. This is a copy of error for each FIS:

> ” Error in ‘MyNetowrk / NODE1/Animation1
>   while executing MATLAB S-function ‘animrule’, flag = 0 (initialize), at start of simulation.
>
> Caused by:
>   Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.”

Can anyone suggest to me how the S function should be look like?